# How to add a CEditor as a page to a MultiPageEditorPart without memory leaks?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, editor, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to add a CEditor as a page to a custom MultiPageEditorPart. Something like:

```
@Override
protected void createPages(){
  myEditor = new CEditor();
  addPage(myEditor , getEditorInput());
...
```

The problem is that *myEditor* is leaked and this can result in big memory leaks. The memory leaks are caused by different listeners that are not removed(CInformationProvider.EditorWatcher is a partListener, selectionChangeListeners of AdaptedSourceViewer, etc.)

Comparing with the opening of an independent CEditor I discovered that my editor was not closed (see WorkbenchPage->closeEditor methods) due to the fact that its site is a PartSite (MultiPageEditorPart creates by default for its pages a MultiPageEditorSite).

I changed the editor site of my CEditor page to an EditorSite. Afterwards the editor was no longer leaked, but it was still not closed properly since another object was still leaking. In addition the keyBinding was no longer working. Still trying to make this solution work, but it seems to complicated to be the correct approach.

Am I missing something? Adding an editor as a page should not cause so many problems.